# I want to incorporate bootstrap-icons in an angular project but it is not working

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-icons

I want to implement bootstrap-icons in an angular project but it is not working. I ran the following command,

npm i bootstrap-icons

But I am unable to add icons in the web page with icon fonts.

For now, I have added the bootstrap icon CDN in index.html file and it is working.

I want to know if we need to add the path for bootstrap icon file anywhere in the angular.jason file or it should work after the install command.

Your answers are appreciated!!!

Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

First, run `npm i bootstrap-icons --save`

then in the *angular.json* file

Add the path to the "Styles" key value like this,

```
"styles": ["node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css",]
```

Answer (score 2):

First install bootstrap icons with npm:

```
npm i bootstrap-icons --save
```

Then go to your `angular.json` file and add this to your styles:

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
        ],
```

Now you can use whatever icon you want.
ex.:

```
<i class="bi bi-bootstrap-fill"></i>
```

If you don't want to use `npm` to use bootstrap icons, you might look at: https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#install

Answer (score 0):

Installing a package to your project via `npm` just downloads the package files to `node_modules`. You would have to configure your project to import the necessary files in order to utilise the package.

In this case, since it is a icons library, you probably have a stylesheet which you already pointed out works via CDN inclusion in the html file.

In angular, try importing the `bootstrap-icons.css` file into your `styles.css` file. You would need to check where the bootstrap-icons folder is in node_modules and find the css file within the folder structure.

From my local install, I identify the location to be: `node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css`

[image: bootstrap-icons.css file location]

In your `styles.css` file, add the import statement:
`@import '~bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';`

This should get your icons working. If not, ensure the `bootstrap-icons.css` file path is correct and accessible.

Attaching a working example (hosted on stackblitz):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-icons?file=src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Hi @DineshKP. Thank you for answering.
In your opinion which of the two is a better practice? Using CDN or importing the file to style.css in angular?

Comment: I think installing them locally, so It doesn't matter if the cdn is down or not, you have a copy of them on your server

Comment: Assuming you would use a CDN on your front-end deployment, adding it as a NPM dependency would be good since it enables intelli-sense on your code editor out of the box without additional configuration which would be required when you import via URL

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing the issue. After importing the icon CSS file at style.css it is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use the CDN version in your **index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.2/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
```

And inside your components:

```
<i class="bi bi-xbox"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has upgraded to Angular 17 below are the steps:

1. run `npm i bootstrap-icons --save`
2. in the styles.css file enter `@import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css';`

N.B. Many answers on the web report @import '~bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css'; **(note the tilde)** but it is now **deprecated** to use the tilde